# Ecto: How to preload records with selecting another joined columns

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Are there any ways to preload records by selecting another joined columns?

```
# table structure
# User 1---* Post 1---* PostTag *---1 Tag

# extract definition of scheme
scheme "posts" do
 ...
 has_many :post_tags, PostTag
 has_many :tags, [:post_tags, :tag]
end
```

Following pseudo-code expresses my goal(but not work).

```
query = from post in Post,
  join: user in User, on post.user_id == user.id,
  select: %{
    id: post.id,
    title: post.title,
    user_name: user.name, # <= column at joined table
  },
  preload: [:tags]
Repo.all(query)
#=> ** (Ecto.QueryError) the binding used in `from` must be selected in `select` when using `preload` in query:`
```

I expect the result like this.

```
[
  %{id: 1, title: "AAA", user_name: "John", tags: [%{name: "elixir"},...]},
  %{id: 2, title: "BBB", user_name: "Mike", tags: [%{name: "erlang"},...]},
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As the error message says, you need to select the binding you gave in `from` when you are preloading, otherwise Ecto has no place to put the preloaded tags. Here is a simple answer:

```
query = from post in Post,
  join: user in User, on: post.user_id == user.id,
  select: {post, user.name},
  preload: [:tags]
```

By returning a tuple, you can have the full post and the user.name on the side. Another approach is to return both post and users as full structs:

```
query = from post in Post,
  join: user in User, on: post.user_id == user.id,
  preload: [:tags, user: user]
```

or if you don't want all fields:

```
query = from post in Post,
  join: user in User, on: post.user_id == user.id,
  preload: [:tags, user: user],
  select: [:id, :title, :user_id, user: [:name]]
```

Comment: Can I filter preloaded multiple record(e.g: `tags`) like `user`? I try to use custom query `tag_q = from tag in Tag, select: [:id, :name]`, and pass preload section(`preload: [tags: ^tag_q]`). This can run, but tags fields are not filtered.

Comment: You can do the same you did for users: `select: [:id, :title, :user_id, user: [:name], tags: [:id, :name]]`. The query should have worked too.

Comment: Many thanks. That's exactly I wanted to do.
When I try `select: [:id, :user_id, user: [:name], tags: [:name]]`, I get NoPrimaryKeyValueError. But I think that's not a big problem.  I can get result as desired by `select: [:id, :user_id, user: [:id, :name], tags: [:name]]`.