# Ecto Query with Select and Preload not working

Tags: elixir, ecto

I cant figure out why my query doesn't work

```
def query_user_public_cards (user_id) do
  User
  |> where([u], u.id == ^user_id)
  |> join(:inner, [u], _ in assoc(u, :memberships))
  |> join(:inner, [..., membership], _ in assoc(membership, :items))
  |> where([..., item], item.active == true)
  |> join(:inner, [..., item], _ in assoc(item, :cards))
  |> where([..., card], card.active == true)
  |> where([..., membership, item, card], card.language_id in [membership.teacher_lg_id, membership.student_lg_id])
  |> select([u, ...], %{user_id: u.id, email: u.email, token: u.token})
  |> preload([u, membership, item, card], [memberships: {membership, items: {item, cards: card}}])
end
```

The Ecto Query looks fine :

```
#Ecto.Query<from u in Everlearn.Members.User, join: m in assoc(u, :memberships),
join: i in assoc(m, :items), join: c in assoc(i, :cards), where: u.id == ^1,
where: i.active == true, where: c.active == true,
where: c.language_id in [m.teacher_lg_id, m.student_lg_id],
select: %{user_id: u.id, email: u.email, token: u.token},
preload: [memberships: {m, [items: {i, [cards: c]}]}]>
```

But I keep getting that error :

```
(Ecto.QueryError) the binding used in `from` must be selected in `select` when using `preload` in query:
```

Any idea ?

Comment: check the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557128/ecto-how-to-preload-records-with-selecting-another-joined-columns)